# Formatting a string in .net for printing a pdf file with Foxit reader

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-formatting, foxit

I need help in formatting a string in C#.Simple one, but can't get the fog of my mind.

I have a foxit reader which reads the .pdf file and prints it on to the printer, the user chooses.

MergerPDF.destinationfile is the location of file

```
PrinterName = @"Companyhi-spdSupply";
commandLine.Arguments = " //t " + mergedPDF.destinationfile + " " + PrinterName;
```

We are trying to execute it from C# code, which triggers a generic syntax error.
Here is the program call statement :

```
commandLine.Arguments?  " //t C:\\EDR Parser\\EDR\\2016-05-27_09-07_Zero.pdf Comapnyhi-spdSupply"
```

We have the command line  printing , which is **working**, when we give this command:

```
/t "C:\EDR Parser\EDR\2016-05-26_10-56_non_Zero.pdf" Companyhi-spdSupply
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without gettign too fancy, if commandline.Arguments will take it

```
commandLine.Arguments = @" /t """  + @mergedPDF.destinationfile.Replace("\\\\", "\\") + @""" " + PrinterName;
```

the output string is

```
/t "C:\EDR Parser\EDR\2016-05-27_09-07_Zero.pdf" Companyhi-spdSupply
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to produce the correct output for me:

```
var PrinterName = "Comapnyhi-spdSupply";
var DestFile = "C:\\EDR Parser\\EDR\\2016-05-27_09-07_Zero.pdf";
var Arguments = " /t \"" + DestFile + "\" " + PrinterName;
Console.WriteLine(Arguments);
```

Output:

> /t "C:\EDR Parser\EDR\2016-05-27_09-07_Zero.pdf" Comapnyhi-spdSupply

It looks like you tried to escape the "/" when you don't need to, and you didn't add the embedded quotes around the filename with \"

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment yet, but give this a try:

remove the extra `'/'` in `//t`
you don't need to escape the slash character.

```
commandLine.Arguments?  " /t C:\\EDR Parser\\EDR\\2016-05-27_09-07_Zero.pdf Comapnyhi-spdSupply"
```